# Rear Derailleur Cage Plate Catching Chain at Lower Pulley

Tags: chain, derailleur

Just got a new Felt (Z85, 2015). Was adding oil and cycling through the gears of the rear derailleur when the chain got caught on the lowest gear.

It appears that the cage plate is catching at the lower pulley. See the attached pictures.

Is this a straightforward fix or should I take it to the store.

Thanks!

[image: Image 1. Closeup underside view]

[image: Image 2. Underside view]

Comment: Your chain is too short.

Comment: Took me a second to realize the bike was upside down on the second picture lol i was like how the hell... but yeah, need more links in the chain. :)

Comment: Although the chain is too short, its a 2x up the front and look like its on the big chain ring. Really should not be in this gear. Could you also post a pic of in on small-small so we can see if a longer chain will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically your chain is too short / largest gears are too large. You should probably take it back to get a longer chain or smaller cassette, especially if it is still on waranty.